# Content Type based template not working for Medical Zymphonies Theme

Tags: theming

I downloaded the [Medical Zymphonies](https://www.drupal.org/project/medical_zymphonies_theme) Theme and has been modifying that to create my own theme.

In the past, I have successfully used content type-specific template files with themes that I created. However, it is not working the current theme.
[This is the template file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/941e9735d44c95b5c4a2bbabf08f48c0) for the theme.

I want a template specifically to basic page. So something like page--basic-page.tpl.php.

Comment: You've probably just forgotten the theme suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193910/drupal-7-how-to-override-page-tpl-for-specific-content-type

Answer (score 0):

JamieR has provided a snippets in [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656#comment-4662688)

```php
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    // If the node type is "blog_madness" the template suggestion will be "page--blog-madness.tpl.php".
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $vars['node']->type;
  }
}
```